# How to decrypt cookie?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've just caught a crash reported on sentry, I am trying to debug and see the root cause for the problem.

Luckily, in the cookies panel, I can see the `laravel_session` value that was used while crash happened.

The question, is, how can decrypt the cookie?

Comment: You can do it like: `$value = Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('xyz'));`

Comment: I got invalid payload

Comment: You must decrypt the value with the same key used to encrypt it.

Comment: I don't know where to get the key that laravel uses to encrypt cookie.. where to find it?

Comment: You can find the encription key at the .env file of the laravel project.

Comment: Did you mean `APP_KEY`

Answer (score 6):

You can decrypt the cookie with the following code:

```
    $cookie = 'eyJpdiI6ImFUQ0FvMWFSVlNvTmhlQjdLWGw1Z1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicFh6Q09iTDl0K0huWU1Nc1NYVmxSY2hPRGU5Vk85dDJyYUpRbUVjRWg5R0JxYkVobkF3YkZVcVQrakFFUmxaVnZrTjFST3F3RTZ4akpDZEpvUFJiQXc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjlhYmJhMTY3MWMxYWI3YjJmNmFjMmNkZWE0MWZmMmVhNTNiMjI5ZWY3NzUwNzQ0ZjAzMGQ1ZGU0YzVhNjJmZGYifQ==';
    $cookie_contents = json_decode( base64_decode( $cookie, true ));
    $value = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->value );
    $iv = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->iv );
    $clear = unserialize( \openssl_decrypt($value, \Config::get( 'app.cipher' ), \Config::get( 'app.key' ), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
    echo "Cookie contents (Session ID): $clear\n";
```

You should end up with a session ID that looks something like this:

- Laravel 5.1: 55782b00dbfcc3f848585ac2cefc66802d773cf5
- Laravel 5.4: yPjeV74joY4MtMNNtTpeOYBP2CMixJBBChc9HRND

I didn't test with Laravel 5.3, but I'm confident it will work.

When using this code, make sure you paste the entire contents of the cookie into the `$cookie` variable, including the two equals signs at the end.

Comment: This is awesome. Any ideas for something similar with Laravel 6's session cookies?

Answer (score 4):

For laravel 6 I think it's pretty much the same

```php
$base64_key = "base64:ISAcSPwQ0HDqqLygaS9LyPzs5ZujMAKOjBou+gyz9sw=";
$payload = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE["your_cookie_name"]), true);
$iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);
$key = base64_decode(substr($base64_key, 7));
$sessionId = openssl_decrypt($payload['value'],  'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);

echo "Session Id: $sessionId";
```

But check few things:

- Cipher encoding, mine is 'AES-256-CBC', it can be 'AES-128-CBC' if your key length is 16
- Key format, mine start with "base64:" so I have to remove this part first

Comment: works for Laravel 8.x. But something mut be wrong for cookies not getting direct access and decrypted using $request->cookie('value')

Comment: I get the laravel cookie like this:
$app_name = \Str::slug(trim(env('APP_NAME'), '_');

$laravelCookie = $_COOKIE[ $app_name . "_session"];